# Jupyter notebook not launching from Anaconda Navigator (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

Firstly, sorry for my english, I'm Brazillian, but let's start it...

I start to study Python some minutes ago through an online course on Udemy. One of the first units was about python environment configuration. I have already installed VS Code, Python 3.7, pip 18.1 without problem. After this, I went to install Anaconda, so I have downloaded this file: "Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh" and intaslled it normally. The problem started when I try to open Anaconda-Navigator through terminal by typing: "cd /anaconda3/bin" and "./anaconda-navigator". After this I tried launch Jupyter Notebook, but it didn't work, just showed it loading, but didn't open any window. When I opened the terminal, I saw this message:

> 2019-09-13 07:50:42,247 - ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:1064
>   ''
>
> /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/conda_api.py:1364:
>   YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated,
>   as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read
>   https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details. data = yaml.load(f)
>   2019-09-13 07:50:50,834 - ERROR download_api._download:234 Invalid url
>   https://www.anaconda.com/wp-content/uploads/Screen-Shot-2018-07-16-at-10.21.36-AM.png
>
> 2019-09-13 07:50:53,729 - ERROR download_api._download:234 Invalid url
>   https://www.anaconda.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Screen-Shot-2018-05-23-at-5.52.25-PM.png
>
> 2019-09-13 07:51:05,310 - ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:1064
>   ''
>
> 2019-09-13 07:51:06,543 - ERROR download_api._download:234 Invalid url
>   https://www.anaconda.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Webinar20-20Three20Ways20to20Move20your20Data20Science20Projects20to20Production.png
>
> 2019-09-13 07:57:00,003 - ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:1064
>   ''
>
> 2019-09-13 08:00:23,009 - WARNING conda_api.communicate:260 Problem
>   parsing conda json output. Line 0. Data - /nThe environment is
>   inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully/nThe following
>   packages are causing the inconsistency:/n/n -
>   defaults/linux-64::numba==0.44.1=py37h962f231_0/n{'fetch':'dask-core-2.3.0
>   | 577 KB | ','finished':false,'maxval':1,'progress':0.027708}/n. Error
>   - Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
>
> 2019-09-13 08:00:24,721 - ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:1064
>   ''
>
> 2019-09-13 08:01:41,774 - ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:1064
>   ''
>
> 2019-09-13 08:02:59,872 - ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:1064
>   ''

I tried looking for a solution by myself, open everything insde
Anaconda Navigator, I saw something out of date, for example "python"
was selected was "2.7 version", btw, I updated everything as I could
and opened Anaconda Navigator again. Jupyter Notebook still doesn't
working, but the current error message is:

> "2019-09-13 08:46:57,673 - ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:1064
>   ''
>
> /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/conda_api.py:1364:
>   YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated,
>   as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read
>   https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details. data = yaml.load(f)
>   2019-09-13 08:47:06,393 - ERROR download_api._download:234 Invalid url
>   https://www.anaconda.com/wp-content/uploads/Screen-Shot-2018-07-16-at-10.21.36-AM.png
>
> 2019-09-13 08:47:09,311 - ERROR download_api._download:234 Invalid url
>   https://www.anaconda.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Screen-Shot-2018-05-23-at-5.52.25-PM.png
>
> 2019-09-13 08:47:18,749 - ERROR download_api._download:234 Invalid url
>   https://www.anaconda.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Webinar20-20Three20Ways20to20Move20your20Data20Science20Projects20to20Production.png

As you see, it's smaller than before, thank you for helping!

PS: I opened Jupyter Notebook successfuly by typing on terminal: "cd /anaconda3/bin" and "./jupyter-notebook". Firstly the access was denied, but it works if you type: "./jupyter-notebook --allow-root". If someone knows hot to fix the problem to open by Anaconda Navigator, please help me!